# Creating booking system in customer portal

Tags: apex, visualforce

Is it possible to implement a booking system in the customer portal, allowing contacts to book appointments with the account manager (for the client they belong to)?
I notice that Salesforce has a calender feature, when users book an appointment can we use this to store the data into? and possible crosscheck to avoid double bookings?

What would be the easiest implementation of this?

Comment: is there any reason you want to use customer portal ? you can simply use a visualforce page in a force.com site to capture the customer & appointment details and create a calendar event between the customer & the account manager.

Comment: Well it needs to be accessible via Customer Portal so customers can access the function. How would I go about creating the two way interaction so that it checks first to make sure there is not an appointment booked for that time?

Comment: you can define 30 or 60 mins appointments in a day.. then query & access calendar events in your controller.. and display only the available slots to the customer in your VF page for them to select.. also to be safe, you can check for already existing events in a selected time slot before creating new events to avoid double booking.. you can use this VF page & controller either in a force.com site or in portals.